# Having users reference nodes of a tree structure

Tags: python, serialization, tree, enumeration

I am writing an app which stores hierarchical data in a tree structure of python class instances.  The root node will have a list of children and each child will also have their own children in a list, and so on.

Users will need to operate directly on the tree structure in an easy way.  The easiest way being enumerated hierarchical list.

1. Lizards
2. Waterfowls

   1. Goose

So for example if a user wanted to add some data to Goose in the command line they would need to work on item 2 sub item 1 or 2.1.

What's the best way to maintain these accessible references to these tree node instances?

Every node has a timestamp and uuid.  The problem is everytime program is run it must be serialized and deserialized.  We will sort by timestamp but I am just a bit unsure how to come up the enumeration, if it should be dynamically done or stored in the tree structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = None
        self.children = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def add_node(self, child):
        child.set_parent(self)
        self.add_child(child)

    def get_node(self, pos):
        try:
            return self.children[pos]
        except IndexError:
            raise ValueError('Node does not exist')

    def access(self, string):
        node = self
        for i in map(lambda i: int(i)-1, string.split('.')):
            node = node.get_node(i)
        return node

    def set_parent(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

>>> n = Node('Root')
>>> l = Node('Lizards')
>>> w = Node('Waterfowls')
>>> g = Node('Goose')
>>> n.add_node(l)
>>> n.add_node(w)
>>> w.add_node(g)
>>> n.access('1')
'Lizards'
>>> n.access('2')
'Waterfowls'
>>> n.access('2.1')
'Goose'
>>> w.access('1')
'Goose'
```

Comment: Hey @Scorpion_God
I guess I don't understand what you mean by this line



           if 0 <= pos < len(self.children):

Comment: @Biff `0 <= pos < len(self.children)` is the same as `0 <= pos and pos < len(self.children)`. What this does is check whether `pos` is in the range `[0, len(self.children))`. In other words, it's making sure that you are not going to get some random `IndexError` when you use an invalid value for `pos`.

Comment: @Biff I will change it to a `try/except` instead though, as that is more clear.